# What use case has the reload() function of a FirebaseUser in flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

What is the method .reload() from the FirebaseUser used for?
Locally the function doesn't change any data, and with Firestore.instance.currentUser() i would always get the current data, wouldn't I?

From the docs:

> public Task reload ()
>   Manually refreshes the data of the current user (for example, attached providers, display name, and so on).

So I originally thought after calling user.reload() the output would be: "name of user: bar" and not "name of user: foo". **So for me it seems like it doesn't really do anything?**

*Related side-question*:
Also that means that I always have to call FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() to be sure to have to current information of the user? There's no way to have a stream of FirebaseUser, which emits a new FirebaseUser when user information is changed? (I don't mean Firebase.instance.onAuthStateChanged() )

Example:

```
 static stackOverflowProblem() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print("Name of User: ${user.displayName}"); //prints foo

    //Renaming the name from "foo" to "bar"
    UserUpdateInfo userInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userInfo.displayName = "bar";
    await _auth.updateProfile(userInfo);

    print("\nBefore calling user.reload:");
    print("Name of user: ${user.displayName}"); //prints foo
    print("Name of FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser: ${(await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).displayName}"); //prints bar

    await user.reload();

    print("\nAfter calling user.reload:");
    print("Name of user: ${user.displayName}"); //prints foo
    print("Name of FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser: ${(await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).displayName}"); //prints bar
  }
```

Console output:

```
I/flutter (19989): Name of User: Foo
I/flutter (19989): 
I/flutter (19989): Before calling user.reload:
I/flutter (19989): Name of user: Foo
I/flutter (19989): Name of FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser: bar
I/flutter (19989): 
I/flutter (19989): After calling user.reload:
I/flutter (19989): Name of user: Foo
I/flutter (19989): Name of FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser: bar
```

Comment: Answer on how `reload()` is supposed to work below. I'm not sure why in your case the second print still shows the old user name though. I hope someone else spots the problem there.

Comment: So my theory how it **should** work is correct, but the implementation is probably incorrect?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lets you verify email without logging out, and logging in again. BUT it might be a bug, but when you call user.reload(), you have to call currentUser() again.

This does not work:

```
await user.reload();
user.isEmailVerified => still false
```

You need to:

```
await user.reload();
user = await _auth.currentUser();
user.isEmailVerified => now it is true
```

Comment: user = _auth.currentUser; worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Calling `User.reload()` reloads that user's profile data from the server.

A typical use-case for this is when you [send an email to the user to verify their email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email). When the user clicks the link in that email it goes back to the Firebase Authentication servers, which mark their email address as verified. But when this happens, there is no way for your app to know about it, since the call went straight from the email client to the server. So often you'll add a so-called [continue URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) to the link, which can call back into your app after the email address was verified. Then your app can call `reload()` to load the updated state from the server.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  
Okay so `user.reload()` is used to update user data which is prone to change, e.g. `displayName`, `photoUrl`, `isEmailVerified`, etc, and only that, as other data e.g. `uid` is constant? So it is better than just getting a new user, as it marginally saves  bandwidth? Because in your example one could have also just requested `currentUser()` instead of calling `reload()`, correct?

Comment: If the user was already signed in, requesting `auth.currentUser()` does not refresh their profile data from the server.

Comment: Ahh okay, I didn't know that, thank you. But why does it seems like it works in that way in my example?? I mean then the first `Name of FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser:` should have been "foo" and not "bar", if `auth.currentUser()` does not refresh the profile data, as i didn't call `user.reload()` yet, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the intended behavior.

Like it was already said only calling `.reload` does not work.

```dart
await user.reload();
print(user.emailVerified) // false
```

Instead you also have to get the `currentUser` again.

```dart
await user.reload();
// `currentUser` is synchronous since FirebaseAuth rework
user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
print(user.emailVerified) // true
```

With the rework (`firebase_auth: ^0.18.0`) `FirebaseAuth` does also expose a `.userChanges()`-Stream.
This seems to be the preferred solution instead of manually reloading the user information.

From the documentation of `FirebaseAuth.userChanges()`:

> This is a superset of both [authStateChanges] and [idTokenChanges]. It
> provides events on all user changes, such as when credentials are
> linked, unlinked and when updates to the user profile are made. The
> purpose of this Stream is to for listening to realtime updates to the
> user without manually having to call [reload] and then rehydrating
> changes to your application.

Taken from the comments below it does not seem to work for `.isEmailVerified` though.

```dart
firebaseAuth.userChanges().listen((user) {
  // Your logic
});
```

Comment: When I verify email, userChanges() doesn't trigger. However, user.reload(), returns emailVerified = true.

Comment: @bounxye same for me. I have to use user.reload() Maybe we are doing something wrong?

Comment: This is the reason why email verification won't fire the event: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3817

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, but the weird way Firebase Auth works, and they say it won't change for now, so I made a package to fix this, grab it here: [firebase_user_stream](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_user_stream)

In the Readme I explain the issues and how the package fixes them, there are examples and etc, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by waiting 2 seconds before calling for the updated data. It is possible that the backend takes some time to update.

pseudo-code as shown below

```
_auth.updateProfile(userInfo);
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), (){
    print("Name of user: ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).displayName}"); //prints bar

});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need use .then or whenComplete in order to get the latest content, for example:

```
await _auth.updateProfile().then((retornedValueFromTheMethod) {
  print(retornedValueFromTheMethod);
}).whenComplete(() {
  print("TODO something if you want");
});
```

You need updateProfile be `Future<retornedValueType> updateProfile() {...}`

Comment: await and that and whenComplete in one expression - is not a good idea