# Reload FirebaseAuth in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

i have created in Flutter the following Code:

```
if (_auth.currentUser != null) {
       &&  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload() != null
      Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    HomeScreen(username: _auth.currentUser.displayName)),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
      );
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 4),
          () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/auth"));
    }
  }
```

The Problem is actually that the Part `&&  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload() != null` is not working.
Do you now why? I want to reaload the currentUser-Firebase-AuthState every time the App is openend.

Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 0):

The [`reload()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reload.html) method is asynchronous and returns a `Future<void>`. You should use the `await` keyword to wait for a future to complete, see [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await).

It is not 100% clear to me why you need to use the [`reload()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reload.html) method. Since you use the `displayName` property in your code, is it because , in your app, this property is frequently changing? I would kindly suggest that you read in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709819/3371862) the explanations on why one should use this method: "Calling `reload()` reloads that user's profile data from the server".

So, if it appears that you really need to use this method, you could do something along the following lines:

```
void navigate() async {

   if (_auth.currentUser != null) {

         await _auth.currentUser.reload();
         // continue your business logic here

         // For example
         if (_auth.currentUser.isEmailVerified) {
            // Navigate to ...
         }

   } else {...}

}
```

---

Note that, as explained [in the FlutterFire doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state), you could alternatively use the [`userChanges()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/userChanges.html) method: "This `stream` provides realtime updates to the `User` class **without having to call `reload()`**, such as when credentials are linked, unlinked and when the user's profile is updated".

Comment: @fynn1307 Hi, did you have time to look at the answer?