# Flutter Firebase reload - No implementation for method User#reload

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

My app workes with Firebase and Flutter. When reload() is launched, I get this error :

*"No implementation found for method User#reload on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth"*

All other firebase functions work, multidexEnabled is true

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Method :

```
  Future<bool> reloadFirebase({required BuildContext context}) async {
    bool _isUserStillConnected = true;
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.reload();
      User? _user = currentUser;
      if(_user == null) {
        _isUserStillConnected = false;
        showDisconnectedDialog(context: context);
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e) {
      _isUserStillConnected = false;
      showDisconnectedDialog(context: context);
    }
    return _isUserStillConnected;
  }
```

call :

```
ListTile(
  onTap: () async {
    bool _isUserStillConnected = await AuthenticationProvider().reloadFirebase(context: context);
    if(_isUserStillConnected) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
        PAGE_ROOM,
        arguments: _roomModels[index],
      );
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that something went wrong with the authentication, so please try the following possible solutions:

- Make sure that you have properly set up the sign-up method in the authentication tab of your firebase console
- Depending on your FB version in yaml file, make sure to import firebase_core
- Check for plugin conflicts / try to use the latest versions from pub.dev
- If it has to do something with the reload() function, maybe try the solution from here, as it might be better for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64899979/15117201