# My Flutter web app logout every time whenever I made change in code in vs code and hot reload

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication on my Flutter Web app, but the session is not persisted after hot restart or refresh in chrome.

In Android it work properly but in web app after hot reload or chrome refresh user logged out.

After googling and finding for about more than 12hr still not I still not get solution.

also follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218629/user-is-turning-null-when-refreshing-chrome-page-flutter-web-firebase) of @frank-van-puffelen 's solution but still facing same problem.

[this ticket](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/3356) is still not resolved.

If possible please run below code.

I look forward to your answer.

Here is my code in `main.dart`

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const AuthGate());
}

class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const FlutterFireUiLogin();
          } else {
            return const Text("You are Logged In");
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my `flutterfire_ui_login.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/auth.dart';

class FlutterFireUiLogin extends StatelessWidget {
  const FlutterFireUiLogin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SignInScreen(
          providerConfigs: const [
            EmailProviderConfiguration(),
            PhoneProviderConfiguration(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  authentication_repository:
    path: packages/authentication_repository
  form_inputs:
    path: packages/form_inputs  
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.5.0
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.3
  rxdart: ^0.27.5
  formz: any
  meta: any
  very_good_analysis: any
  flow_builder: any
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  flutterfire_ui: ^0.4.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.0
  google_sign_in_web: ^0.10.2
  http: ^0.13.4
  path: ^1.8.1
  csv: ^5.0.1
  provider: ^6.0.3
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mocktail: ^0.3.0
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.795], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.8)
    X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio.
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fix has just been released in the latest version 3.6.0.

Comment: Just to be clear, 3.6.0 is a new version of firebase_auth package, not flutter itself.

Comment: I am using 3.11.0, and this issues still occurs. Followed a tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#8