# How to keep a user logged in Flutter web app using Firebase Authentication

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am developing a FLutter web app and using Firebase Authentication with email and password login for signing in users

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

After Successfully signing in, the code redirects the user to a HomePage.

```
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/HomePage');
```

But when the user refreshes the web page or tries to go to the website again, it has signed out and has to log in again.

Following is the code I use to check the logged in user

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
    initialData:  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        if (snapshot.data == null){
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/HomePage');
        }else{
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/signup');
        }
      }
```

How can I keep the user logged in as long as they use log out?
I want the solution to work specifically on flutter web.

Comment: you can save the authentication credentials on the local storage and reuse it.

Comment: check out my answer, same question asked few days ago.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504919/9194671

Answer (score 2):

whatever you are building flutter app, web or desktop. you need to keep recorder of user in share preference. this package shared_preferences: ^2.0.15 support web app too. when user will logout then you must need to remove saved data.
[Click here:](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: We used this library in Flutter WEB and APP (Android) and it works perfectly for your scope.

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: The best example is the official documentation for the `shared_preferences` which can be found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate to signup when data is null and to home otherwise but you are doing it reverse.

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    if (snapshot.data == null){
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/signup');
    }else{
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Homepage');
    }
  }
```