# How can I `reload()` a user's token after updating their custom claims from a server function?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have a server function that updates a user's custom claims.

```
exports.onEmployeeUpdated = functions.firestore
  // When a employee document is updated, if <condition> update isApproved custom claim

  .document('employees/{employeeId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

      // Update the user's existing claims
      const uid = context.params.employeeId
      return getAuth()
        .getUser(uid)
        .then((userRecord) => {
          let claims = userRecord.customClaims
          claims['isApproved'] = false

          // Assign the new claims
          return getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, claims).then(() => {
            // reload() here
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return `Custom claim not updated because no user with id ${uid} exists`
        })
    }
  })
```

My understanding is that [`reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#reload) can be [used to refresh the token from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709819/2146894). But it's not clear to me how to actually invoke `reload()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't force the client to refresh the token on the server side. The reload method you linked to is actually part of the Node.js *client* SDK, and the question you linked you describes how to reload the user on the client side by fetching data from the server side.

[As per the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client), you can refresh the ID token *on the client side* "by calling `getIdToken(true)`".

Example: (using the JS v9 SDK):

```js
import { getIdTokenResult } from "firebase/auth";

const { claims } = await getIdTokenResult(auth.currentUser, true); // true = force a refresh
console.log(claims.isApproved); // should be false
```