# How to refresh Firebase Authentication user without logging off

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter app using Firebase Authentication and email/password authentication.

App is using `StreamProvider` in `main.dart` to get user.

```
  StreamProvider<UserModel?>.value(
                  initialData: null,
                  catchError: (_, op) => null,
                  value: AuthService().user,
                ),
```

Later I call this method to get user info:

```
User? getCurrentUser() {
    return _auth.currentUser;
  }
```

This is working great, I can sign in, sign out, sign up, handle forgotten password. But there is a problem with email verification.

When the user first signs up, `emailVerified` value is, as expected, false.

I use below method to send email verification:

```
await user.sendEmailVerification();
```

However, after user verifies the email, this is not reflected in the user object. Even if the app is closed and started again, the `emailVerified` value is still `false`.

Only after I sign out and sign in again is this refreshed.

As restarting the app does not help, I can assume it is not my code that's problematic. Seems that the user is cached and not refreshed by Flutter or Firebase.

I am thinking I may have to use `reload` method, but would like some guidance on this.

Is it normal that user changes are not visible and reload is required?
When do I need to reload? Every time the app starts?
Do I only do it for accounts that have not been email verified, or are there other updates I could miss?

Comment: There is a [reload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload) method available. It had [its quirks in old version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709733/what-use-case-has-the-reload-function-of-a-firebaseuser-in-flutter), not sure how it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebase Authentication, the user information is initially retrieved when the user signs in or the app starts, and it is not automatically updated in real-time. Therefore, if you perform actions outside the current session, such as email verification, you might not see the updated user information until you explicitly refresh it.

The reload method in Firebase Authentication is used to refresh the user's data, including the emailVerified property. You can call this method to force the user object to be updated with the latest information from the server.

Here's an example of how you can use the reload method:

```
Future<void> reloadUser() async {
  User? user = _auth.currentUser;
  await user?.reload();
  user = _auth.currentUser; // Get the refreshed user object
  // Now, user.emailVerified should reflect the latest status
}
```

You can call this method whenever you want to ensure that the user's information, including the emailVerified status, is up to date. This might be necessary after actions like email verification.

As for when to call the reload method, it depends on your app's requirements. You might want to consider calling it in the following scenarios:

1. After the user performs an action that could change their
   authentication status, such as email verification.
2. When the app
   starts or resumes to ensure the user's information is up to date. In
   response to a specific user interaction, for example, when the user
   navigates to a profile page. Keep in mind that calling reload can
   involve a network request, so you should consider the user
   experience and the performance implications based on your specific
   use case.
3. In summary, it's normal behavior that user changes are not
   automatically reflected in the user object, and you need to use the
   reload method to update it manually when needed.

The frequency of calling reload depends on your app's requirements and the specific scenarios where you want to ensure the user information is up todate.